# Install R packages from github downloading master.zip

Tags: r, github

I probably have some issues in my connectivity (some sort of blocks, I don't know) and I can't install directly form `gitHub`

```
> install_github("assertthat")
Installing github repo(s) assertthat/master from hadley
Installing assertthat.zip from https://github.com/hadley/assertthat/archive/master.zip
```

I tried with lots of other packages, same result. However, I am able to download `master.zip` form the browser. Can you tell if it's possible install directly the `.zip`? thanks.

Comment: The latest dev version of devtools adds an [install_local](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/commit/fb892031953a0f5bde3de48f487030e6e751d232) function that should solve your problem. But, I guess the trouble is installing dev version of devtools in the first place.

Comment: @Ramnath yep.. to have that version of `devtools` you need to get it from `cran` first and then from `gitHub` unfortunately ..

Comment: Try the `install` function on the unzipped directory. It should work. The `install` function ships with the CRAN version of devtools.

Comment: @Ramnath `No DESCRIPTION file found in C:\Users\Michele\Downloads\assertthat-master`

Comment: Strange. I downloaded `asserthat`, unzipped it and ran `install` and it works fine for me.

Comment: @Ramnath I'm just running `install("path")` is there any other parameter to set?

Comment: Nope. Just that, no parameters to set. You could try switching into your Downloads directory and specifying the relative path.

Comment: @Ramnath just forget my last two comments... `istall` worked just fine, you can put that in an answer if you want. Thanks!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This answer is just a refined version of my comments. Essentially you can install packages using `devtools` by unzipping a local zipfile downloaded from github, and then running the `install` function

`install("path/to/unzipped_pkg_zip_file")`

The latest dev version of `devtools` contains an `install_local` utility function that makes it easy to work directly with local zip files.

Comment: I don't have devtools installed. How I can use this approach to get devtools installed first?

Comment: is the "/to/" bit included in the path ?

Could you kindly give an example of a .zip file in the folders ?