# in R, how to install ggbiplot?

Tags: r, installation, ggbiplot

I am running R version 3.2.3 in RStudio. I tried following these instructions:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("ggbiplot", "vqv")
```

and

```
library(devtools)
install_github("vqv/ggbiplot")
```

from here http://www.vince.vu/software/

but I am getting this error:

```
> library(devtools)
> install_github("vqv/ggbiplot")
Downloading GitHub repo vqv/ggbiplot@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/vqv/ggbiplot/zipball/master
Installing ggbiplot
Installing 1 package: ggplot2
Warning: package ‘ggplot2’ is in use and will not be installed
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore CMD INSTALL  \
  "C:/Users/ms/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpSIMFOv/devtools216870196a49/vqv-ggbiplot-7325e88"  \
  --library="\\ymr.corp.rt.org/homedrive$/MS/R/win-library/3.2" --install-tests 

* installing *source* package 'ggbiplot' ...
** R
** data
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
*** arch - i386
Warning in library(pkg_name, lib.loc = lib, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE) :
  there is no package called 'ggbiplot'
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
*** arch - x64
Warning in library(pkg_name, lib.loc = lib, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE) :
  there is no package called 'ggbiplot'
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed for 'i386', 'x64'
* removing '\\ymr.corp.rt.org/homedrive$/MS/R/win-library/3.2/ggbiplot'
Error: Command failed (1)
```

I have searched for answers and tried (unsuccessfully) to follow suggestions here [Instal R packages from github downloading master.zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17366772/instal-r-packages-from-github-downloading-master-zip) and here [how can I offline install ggbiplot using windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29918714/how-can-i-offline-install-ggbiplot-using-windows)

Comment: May be you don't have rights on `\\ymr.corp.rt.org/homedrive$/MS/R/win-library/3.2`, try to use a local library folder

Comment: Thanks. I followed instructions here on how to do that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170399/changing-r-default-library-path-using-libpaths-in-rprofile-site-fails-to-work

Comment: install.packages("devtools")
install.packages("fs")
library(devtools)
install_github("vqv/ggbiplot")
library(ggbiplot)