# Failing to install R package from archive

Tags: r, archive, cran

I want to install the "fume" package on my Windows machine. I tried this by giving the following command in the console:

```
install.packages("https://cran.r- project.org/src/contrib/Archive/fume/fume_1.0.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type ="source", INSTALL_opts = c('--no-lock'))
```

But then I get the following result:

```
* installing *source* package 'fume' ...
** package 'fume' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** data
** preparing package for lazy loading
Warning: package 'chron' was built under R version 3.3.1
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Warning in library(pkg_name, lib.loc = lib, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE) :
  there is no package called 'fume'
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing '\\COMPANY.local/users$/NAME/R/win-library/3.3/fume'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"F:/R/R-33~1.0/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL --no-lock -l "\\COMPAMY.local\users$\NAME\R\win-library\3.3" "C:/Users/NAME~1.NAME/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpKY2Wsg/downloaded_packages/fume_1.0.tar.gz"' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/NAME~1.NAME/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpKY2Wsg/downloaded_packages/fume_1.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Any ideas on how to install this package correctly?

Comment: try downloading the package and install from source and have dependencies as true                                                                                        install.packages("/home/user/Downloads/fume_1.0.tar.gz", repos = NULL, dependencies = TRUE)

Comment: Unfortunately, this gives the same error

Comment: @M3003 look at this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35875757/in-r-how-to-install-ggbiplot it was already answered and the person followed the instruction from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170399/changing-r-default-library-path-using-libpaths-in-rprofile-site-fails-to-work

Comment: Well, it worked on my machine, both windows and linux. Can you do this  install.packages("/home/user/Downloads/fume_1.0.tar.gz",lib = "/home/your_path_for_the_library", repos = NULL, dependencies = TRUE)

Comment: @Dinesh.hmn Thank you! First I got the error ' ERROR: failed to lock directory 'P:/R/win-library/3.3' for modifying
Try removing 'P:/R/win-library/3.3/00LOCK-fume' ', but deleting that folder did the trick

Comment: @M3003 Please post that as an answer and accept it, so others can easily see the solution if they encounter the same problem.