# How to manually install rChart?

Tags: r, rcharts

I can't install rChart from Rstudio due to some firewall settings in my company computer, so I wonder if I can install it manually. I know it is possible to do that by using `install.packages`, but it seems the installation was not successful. Here is what I did:

1. download the master file from https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts
2. used the following code to install:

   > install.packages('\rCharts-master.zip',destdir = "/R/win-library/3.2",repos = NULL)
3. load the package `library(rCharts-master)` and resulted in the following error message:

   `Error in library(rCharts - master) : 'package' must be of length 1`

Comment: hi @chinsoon12, I was not really clear in my question. Due to the firewall settings, I can't access github from Rstudio. I tried the `devtool` and it didn't work.

Comment: hi @chinsoon12, as I'm using a company laptop, I don't have access to the command prompt. That's why I need a manual solution.

Comment: Thank you guys. I actually found the solution from this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17366772/instal-r-packages-from-github-downloading-master-zip

Answer (score 1):

rChart is a package on GitHub, try

install.packages("devtools")

library(devtools)

install_github('ramnathv/rCharts')

library(rCharts)

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the package you're trying to load is "rCharts", and not "rCharts-master". Try

```
library(rCharts)
```

Comment: Hi @andrechalom, I tried that and it returned the following error: `Error in library(rCharts) : ‘rCharts’ is not a valid installed package`