# R install packages on Github(error)

Tags: r

```
library(devtools)

install_github('taiyun/recharts')
```

but R gives me error as follow:

> **Installation failed: schannel: failed to receive handshake, SSL/TLS connection failed**

I don't know why.I think it maybe the network is restriction.

Comment: I think you want to look at this: [instal-r-packages-from-github-downloading-master-zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17366772/instal-r-packages-from-github-downloading-master-zip)

Comment: Well rated answer here as well: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33179156/installing-a-package-offline-from-github]

Comment: Try using this lightweight version. I suspect the outcome will be the same, but it's easier to debug: https://github.com/jtilly/install_github

Comment: Thank you all! Both ways are right way to solve the problem.